# matplotlib: How to add legend of pixel value range?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize an image using the following code. How can I add a legend to this image to represent the value range of pixels?

```
first_layer_activation = activations[31]
print(first_layer_activation.shape)
```

result:`(1, 16, 16, 1)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.matshow(first_layer_activation[0, :, :, 0], aspect='auto', cmap='viridis')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like `plt.colorbar()`?

Comment: yes, how can I add that?

Comment: By calling `plt.colorbar()`. Is it not working for you?

Comment: Thanks, It was successful.